# ¿Cómo agrupar y ordenar datos con libreria lodash en Angular?

Tags: typescript, lodash

estoy usando la libreria `lodash` en `Angular` para agrupar estos datos:

```js
data = 
[
   {
     hash: "13m49k9pg70b",
     fecha_registro: "2021-10-26T20:28:25.350000Z",
     id: 7791,
     nombre: "aprueba"
   },
   {
     hash: "13m49k9pg70b",
     fecha_registro: "2021-10-26T20:28:25.350000Z",
     id: 7792,
     nombre: "aprueba"
   },
   {
     hash: "1sd345612se",
     fecha_registro: "2021-11-08T21:22:25.350000Z",
     id: 7793,
     nombre: "btest"
   },
    {
     hash: "1sd345612se",
     fecha_registro: "2021-11-08T21:22:25.350000Z",
     id: 7794,
     nombre: "btest"
   },
    {
     hash: "asd1w345611s",
     fecha_registro: "2021-08-11T10:22:21.350000Z",
     id: 7794,
     nombre: "cvtest"
   },  

]
```

Lo que hago es agrupar los datos por las propiedades `nombre`, `hash`, `fecha_registro` para ello en una función hago esto:

```js
this.confPersoDocenteClas = _.groupBy(data, (item) => {
    return [ item['nombre'], item['hash'], item['fecha_registro']];
});

console.log("DATA AGRUPADA", this.confPersoDocenteClas)
```

Lo cual me devuelve agrupado correctamente los datos

```js
aprueba,13m49k9pg70b,2021-10-26T20:28:25.350000Z: [{...}, {...}]
btest, 1sd345612se, 2021-11-08T21:22:25.350000Z: [{...}, {...}]
cvtest, asd1w345611s, 2021-11-08T10:12:21.350000Z: [{...}, {...}]
```

El "problema" que tengo es que me devuelve los datos en orden alfabético de la clave  `nombre` , y lo que necesito es que me devuelva ordenado por `fecha_registro`, desde la más reciente a la más antigua, de esta forma:

```js
btest, 1sd345612se, 2021-11-08T21:22:25.350000Z: [{...}, {...}]
cvtest, asd1w345611s, 2021-11-08T10:12:21.350000Z: [{...}, {...}]
aprueba,13m49k9pg70b,2021-10-26T20:28:25.350000Z: [{...}, {...}]
```

Para intentar esto he agregado una linea a la función que indique anteriormente de esta forma:

```js
let datos  = _.orderBy(data, ['fecha_registro'], ['desc']); //linea agregada
this.confPersoDocenteClas = _.groupBy(datos, (item) => {
    return [ item['nombre'], item['hash'], item['fecha_registro']];
});
```

Esto los ordena pero al hacer nuevamente la agrupación se vuelve a ordenar en orden alfabético, en este caso por la clave `nombre`. Cómo puedo hacer para que me devuelva ordenado por `fecha_registro`? Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Saludos. Prueba primero el agrupar; luego ya agrupados ordenarlos claro con el correspondiente tratamiento por la estructura que te genera; ese **lodash** es de gran ayuda y tiene muchas aplicaciones; ahorra un buen de código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una posible solución es, agrupar primero, luego ordenar. Los cambios serían mínimos:

```
groupedData = _.groupBy(this.data, (item) => {
    return [item['nombre'], item['hash'], item['fecha_registro']];
});

finalData = _.orderBy(_.keys(groupedData), (item) => {
  return item.split(',')[2];
}, ['desc']).map(item => {
  return {
    [item]: groupedData[item]
  }
});
```

Usamos `desc` para ordenar desde la fecha más reciente a la más antigua.

En este caso, se usaría una función como segundo parámetro del método `orderBy()`, para poder acceder al atributo que necesitas.

Aquí actualicé el [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lodash-import-qw13wv?file=src/app/app.component.ts) con esta solución.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo. Se ordena por fechas, sin embargo se pierde la estructura original de las claves, y a las claves las necesito

Comment: Ahora actualizo la respuesta

Comment: @FernandoJavierLeón Revisa esta [solución](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lodash-import-qw13wv?file=src/app/app.component.ts). ¿Te sirve?

Comment: Dejé dos posibles soluciones, creo que la más factible es la que dejé comentada, revisa y me dices qué tal.

Comment: ya lo revisé amigo, use lo que estaba comentado en el stackblitz pero aún no se ordena desde la fecha_registro más reciente a la más antigua

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Cuando usas `_.groupBy()` con una función iteradora, el valor que retornas en ella dicta los valores con los cual agrupar y el orden en que aparecerán en la 'key' generada, luego retornará el nuevo objeto con las key ordenadas alfabéticamente.

Para obtenerlas ordenadas según la fecha, esta debería estar primera en el arreglo que retornas en el iterador:

```javascript
this.confPersoDocenteClas = _.groupBy(datos, (item) => {
    return [item['fecha_registro'], item['nombre'], item['hash']];
});
```

Esto te traerá eso sí las `keys` en otro formato (`2021-10-26T20:28:25.350000Z,aprueba,13m49k9pg70b`) y además ordenará alfabéticamente, por lo que vendrán de las mas antiguas a las más recientes. Si quieres re-formatearlos como tú necesitas podrías hacer algo como:

```javascript
// Conseguimos la lista de valores agrupados y la invertimos para conseguir el orden según fecha decreciente
this.confPersoDocenteClas = _.reverse(Object.values(this.confPersoDocenteClas)).reduce((obj, group) => {
    // iteramos sobre las listas para generar el 'key' necesario
    const item = group[0] // Cada grupo tiene al menos un item
    obj[`${item['nombre']},${item['hash']},${item['fecha_registro']}`] = group // recreamos la key
    return obj
}, {});
```

**EDIT:**

Si haces `console.log(...)` del objeto verás las llaves aún alfabéticamente, pero eso no significa que lo estén en el objeto...

Sucede que javascript desde el inicio consideraba a lo objetos como simples hashes de valores que carecían de ordenamiento entre cada llave, es por eso que `console.log()` ordenará siempre las llaves `string` alfabéticamente y las llaves `number` en orden creciente.

Sin embargo, [desde ES6 se definió el orden de iteración sobre éstos](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html) que dice:

> - Primero, las llaves con números enteros en orden ascendente.
> - Luego, todas las llaves `string`, **en el orden que se agregaron en al objeto**.
> - Finalmente, las llaves con símbolos, en el orden que se agregaron en al objeto.

Esto afecta a las funciones en general que usen sus llaves internas para ejecución, como `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()` y `Object.entries()` entre otros.

Es por eso que la respuesta no es errónea, sino que `console.log()` engaña:

```javascript
// Imprime el objeto ordenado alfabéticamente:
console.log(this.confPersoDocenteClas)
/*
{
  aprueba,13m49k9pg70b,2021-10-26T20:28:25.350000Z: [{...}, {...}],
  btest,1sd345612se,2021-11-08T21:22:25.350000Z: [{...}, {...}],
  cvtest,asd1w345611s,2021-08-11T10:22:21.350000Z: [{...}]
}
*/
// Sin embargo Object.keys() retorna el orden correcto
console.log(Object.keys(this.confPersoDocenteClas))
// ["cvtest,asd1w345611s,2021-08-11T10:22:21.350000Z", "btest,1sd345612se,2021-11-08T21:22:25.350000Z", "aprueba,13m49k9pg70b,2021-10-26T20:28:25.350000Z"]
```

Esto muestra que el reparseo es sólo si necesitas tener un objeto con llaves string pero con ordenamiento para usar las funciones de iteracion.

Sino será mas útil usar un arreglo como mostró @Jonatan Lavado ya que ellos sí guardan el ordenamiento en los logs (ya que son básicamente objetos con llaves númericas `0, 1, etc...`)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Japsz, usé tu código, puse la fecha_registro primera en el arreglo del _.groupBy, me devuelve de la más antigua a la más reciente como dices y luego hice el reverse, pero al hacerlo me vuelve a ordenar en orden alfabético

Comment: Los objetos carecen de orden por definición, pero de todos modos es posible definirles un orden para cuando se necesite en otras funciones nativas como `Object.keys()`. Edité mi respuesta con una aclaración